# Jquery DataTables - Table width is shorter than dataTable_wrapper width

Tags: jquery, datatables

How do I correct the issue with the .dataTables_wrapper width being larger than the actual table data width? (using autowidth for the table data). 
I am using oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(); to resize the columns after the page is loaded. Everything looks fine for the column widths, but the wrapper is still too large.

```
var oTable = $('.admin_users').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      //  "sAjaxSource": 'SQL/dataTable.php',
        "bStateSave": true, //Use a cookie to save current display of items
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "date", "sClass":"center" }
        ]

    });
    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
```

Comment: can u show us the datatables config ?

Comment: Just added the config code above. Thanks for looking

Comment: try setting this option: `"bScrollCollapse": true`

Comment: try this? "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "100%"

Comment: That worked! Not sure why, but hey it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:
Add this to the table initilization

```
"fnInitComplete": function() {
                oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
         }
```