# data table grows out of container DIV

Tags: php, jquery, css, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable

```
<div id="wrapperDiv">

<table id="dataTable"> <!-- data --> </table>

<div/>
```

wrapper's width is 960 px and table goes to 1080 px (it has broader data)

I tried

```
-    setting width: 100% in table tag inline CSS
-    setting overflow-x auto; in table tag
```

And promising looking solutions from

[jQuery DataTables: control table width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604933/jquery-datatables-table-width-problem)

[How to set column widths to a jQuery datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590778/how-to-set-column-widths-to-a-jquery-datatable)

[DataTables width problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023224/datatables-width-problem)

[Jquery DataTables - Table width is shorter than dataTable_wrapper width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014658/jquery-datatables-table-width-is-shorter-than-datatable-wrapper-width)

None of them worked for me, As a workaround I increased the width of wrapper DIV to fit the data table.
Any help?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? For the div provide a scroll bar? Or the datatable?  Have you tried "sScrollX":"100%" in the .dataTable() call?  You could also try "sScrollX":"1080".  Also look at sScrollXInner.  It just depends on what you are expecting.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle, i typically set a container div to px width, then the generated datatables wrapper to 100%

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem off and on for months, none of the suggested solutions fixed my problem.  Today I decided to brute-force it and it worked.  It's not the most elegant solution, nor would I say it's the "right" way to do it, but it works and is pretty minimal in its impact.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
            var greatestWidth = 0;
            $('.dataTable').each(function() {
                if (greatestWidth < $(this).width()) {
                    greatestWidth = $(this).width();
                }
            });

            $('#yourcontainer').width(greatestWidth);
        });
```

Basically I just try to find the largest table (would work for height as well) whenever the user scrolls and then set the container to be that width.  The reason I had to do it this way is that I'm using ajax and some APIs to fill in data and settings so the table resizes itself a few times before it is complete.  None of the DataTables complete functions work due to some resizing and reformatting that take place after-the-fact, and $(document).ready() doesn't work because the table is changed after the document loads.

It's ugly but it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the style

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .table-responsive {
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

Define a new class, i called mine "**wrappable**". Adding this class to datatable column class makes it wrap text in cell so it does not overflow to other cells on the right

```
table.dataTable tbody td.wrappable { white-space:normal; }
```

Apply class to column in your dataTable

```
var columns = [ { data: null, title: " Request Details ", className: "all wrappable", width: '200px', sortable: true, autoWidth: false, render: function (data, type, row) { var year = 'Fiscal Year: ' + naIfNullOrEmpty(data.FISCAL_YEAR) + ''; var cycle = 'Cycle: ' + naIfNullOrEmpty(data.CdSnfCycle.NAME) + ''; var notes = '
Notes: ' + naIfNullOrEmpty(data.NOTES) + ' '; return year + cycle + notes; } }, ]
```

Hope this helps somebody